# Group such that Aut(G) = H and Aut(H) = G

Tags: group-theory

So this question just popped into my mind: does there exist a group $G$ such that $Aut(G) = H$ and $Aut(H) = G$ and $H\not=G$. My intuition says no, but im not sure how to go about proving this. Can somebody find an example or knows how to prove such a statement?

Comment: This is the same as asking whether there exists a group for which $Aut(Aut(G))\cong G$. This seems to be unknown. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27861/periodic-automorphism-towers

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Maybe I'm not understand the question: the automorphism group of $S_n$ is $S_n$ for $n$ not six.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: sorry, I was assuming $Aut(G)\not\cong G$.

Comment: Oh, sure. The OP is doing so too.