# Are there groups $G$ isomorphic to $\mathrm{Aut}\left( \mathrm{Aut} (G)\right)$, such that $G\not\cong \mathrm{Aut}(G)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples

Trivial examples for the first condition are easy to find: $G={1},C_2$.

Are there any (finite\non-finite) groups that satisfy the conditions in the title?

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/5635/does-mathrmaut-mathrmaut-mathrmautg-stabilize If the group G is finite and centerless then the sequence of Aut's stabilizes, so this cannot happen. In that question, and in the link to Thomas' book there are tons of information.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1710853 and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27861/periodic-automorphism-towers